# Why do you need to' in this sentence? ("I wouldn't go so far as to say that computers will replace teachers in the near future.")

Tags: grammar

Example sentence:

> I wouldn't go so far as **to** say that computers will replace teachers in the near future.

Why do you need "to" in this sentence?

Comment: [CD]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-so-far-as-to-do) shows the complete expression 'go so far as to [do something]'. Compare 'venture **_to_** [say something]': "May I venture to add the latest information we've just received?"

Answer (score 3):

As @PaulTanenbaum points out, that's the rule. But that doesn't say **why**.

The *to* that occurs before infinitives marks the constituent following *to* as the verb phrase of an infinitive (uninflected, tenseless) clause. It's part of the *for ... to* complementizer (a part of speech that the Romans never discovered) which distinguishes infinitives from other kinds of untensed constituents.

- *[**For** Bill **to** arrive early] was a bad idea.*
  (*for* marks the subject, *to* marks the verb phrase, and the whole infinitive clause is the subject of *was*)
- ***It** was a bad idea [**for** Bill **to** arrive early.]*
  (Extraposition inserts a dummy *it* and moves the infinitive subject to the end)

The *for* is usually not present, and quite often the whole subject of an infinitive is missing. But you can always figure out what it is:

- ***It** was a bad idea [**to** arrive early.]*  (somebody -- maybe the speaker -- arrived early)
- *I want [(for) Bill **to** arrive early]*. (Bill arrives early; many people can use *for* here)

Infinitives are pervasive and common in many idioms; I could go on for a long time here. But the reason for the *to* is to mark an infinitive **as** an infinitive, so you can tell what you can do with it.

Comment: You've missed out the bit where you say that the *as*-clause here is the complement of *so*.

Comment: Oh, well; can't do everything :-)

Comment: Thought I'd sneak that in as I can't leave an answer (not that I have time to).

Answer (score 0):

Because that’s the idiom. There’s really no better reason than that. One might as well ask why the *to* is needed in

> I want **to** eat ice cream.

or

> What gave you the idea **to** look under the couch?

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of certain verbs like *help* — or after modal verbs like *can, might, will — to* is **always** needed for the second verb in an expression.

> I come **to bury** Caesar.
> I need **to eat**.
> I wouldn't † go **to meet**... [† no *to* at this point]

Comment: But this isn't the second verb in a catenation of verbs. It is the verb phrase following the equative preposition *as*.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this sentence:

> They went as far as London.

**London** is a place, and it makes sense with *far*, which literally refers to a distance. The opposite of **near**.

But **far** can be used figuratively, and in this figurative use, physical distance becomes an analog for the abstract notion of *extreme extent*, and the *going* becomes an analog for an *action* (of some kind: doing, saying):

```
   go : far   ::   do or say : something extreme
```

Going far becomes an analog for doing or saying something extreme.

Now, some more abstract ideas. The *action* called for by this figurative use, **go as far as [action]**, has to be expressed as a *nominal*, that is, as something noun-like. London, in our literal example of **far**, was a noun of place; the action in our figurative use of **far** must be a pure noun of action.

In English, the marked infinitive, the form with **to** + bare verb, is a pure noun of action; it can stand as the direct object of a verb or as the subject in a sentence:

> I wanted **to go** but  **to leave** was impossible.

And so we use the marked infinitive:

> I would not go as far as ***to say* we were dying of thirst**. But we were very dehydrated and feeling lightheaded.
>
> I would not go as far as ***to throw* the mobile phone in the recycling bin** when all it needed was a new battery.